# tdeSDK - db.execute wont return any data on Windows 7

Tags: sqlite, tidesdk

I am using tidesdk 1.3.1-beta with tideSDK Developer 1.4.2. I am using a pre-loaded sqlite3 database to display data in my app. My problem is db.execute(select * ... statement doesn't return any data however i can see that the table contains data. However db.execute is successful while creating any table or inserting records to the table. The web inspector just shows a "not found" error.

Also i am not able to increase the loglevel by setting Ti.API.setLogLevel(7);

Here is the code snippet.

```
var db = Ti.Database.openFile(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getApplicationDataDirectory(), 'new.db'));  
db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BOOKS (TITLE  VARCHAR, AUTHORS VARCHAR");
var rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM BOOKS");
while (rows.isValidRow()) { 
    document.getElementById("area").innerHTML += "<br>" + rows.fieldByName('TITLE');
    rows.next();    
}
```

Comment: Uhm, your SQL statement in line 2 is broken.

Comment: You can safely ignore line 2. Just assume books table has data. But somehow its not displayed. The db.execute line doesnt show anything.[19:04:40:552] [Ti.JavaScript.JSUtil] [Debug] Evaluating JavaScript file at: C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\ui\1.3.1-beta\ui.js
[19:04:40:578] [Ti.File] [Debug] ToString: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\TideSDK\XXX\libdb.sqlite
[19:04:40:591] [Ti.Database.DB] [Debug] Execute called with SELECT * FROM BOOKS
[19:04:40:666] [Ti.Proxy] [Debug] Looking up proxy information for: https://api.appcelerator.net/p/v1/app-track

Answer (score 0):

can you please file an issue with TideSDK here: https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues

This looks like a bug. We will checkout the same.

Thanks for reporting the same.

Comment: Hi,I have already filed a bug (#104) for the same. Have found a workaround for this. Providing column names instead of * works properly.

Comment: Another update: Seems like number of columns retrieved in a sql query is the cause. If I want to query my entire table, I cannot use all my columns. I must query with a limited number of columns. This is a big SHOW-STOPPER. This needs to be fixed ASAP.